# Django/Wsgi/Apache throws Premature end of script errors and none of the usual solutions work

Tags: django, apache, nginx, mod-wsgi, wsgi

After a very standard and minor release, our Apache/Nginx/Django/wsgi setup ceased to function with the dreaded

Premature end of script headers: django.wsgi

message in the log. There is no segfault anywhere and no other error message.

There is no expat problem (checked with sample wsgi app with and without that module include). 
The server was working fine. The codebase was updated slightly and apache restarted when the horrors began.

Here is my wsgi file:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append('/home/app/')
sys.path.append('/home/app/topmodule/')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app.settings'
os.environ["CELERY_LOADER"] = "django"

import app.settings
import django.core.handlers.wsgi

application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

The apache conf for this site is:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/app/topmodule/django.wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess app user=app group=app processes=6 threads=1
WSGIProcessGroup app
```

I also tried adding:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

but no help there. 
All I'm getting is an apache Server error page and that damn premature-end error in the error log.

I did try to roll back the codebase but that didn't do any good either which leads me to suspect its not a new code issue.

**EDIT**
I've narrowed the segfault to a line in Django's wsgi.py.

Trace:

http://paste.pocoo.org/show/546803/

Some dumps:

http://paste.pocoo.org/show/546846/

This happens when requesting any url.
Middleware used:

```
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
```

Comment: This is Python 2.6.4, django 1.3.1, apache 2 on Debian Squeeze

Comment: and you double checked that django **still is** on the syspath, isn't it? how is it installed? virtualenv? global pip install?

Comment: Its installed via pip (global). 
Here's my sys.path:
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python26.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL']

Comment: If i place the hello world wsgi application after all of my regular django application call in my wsgi file (overriding the django one) it works and I do get the hello world.

Comment: I've ran wsgi through the python debuger, and the trace is pasted in the link below. Note that the error is on django/core/handlers/wsgi.py when getting the response: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/546803/

Comment: what is 'glowconsole.middleware.ViewNameMiddleware'? can you try removing it? Or paste its content?

Comment: please ignore it, its been removed. some redundant code that did nothing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reinstalling apache, mod wsgi and all related packages. At some point a warning error came up that mod_wsgi was compiled against Python 2.6.6 while the runtime is Python 2.6.4.
I rebuilt Python from source to 2.6.6 and the problem was resolved. I'm not sure if it was the minor version update or the whole rebuild that fixed it. I'm also not sure why it worked until now, and suddenly stopped working but at least its all OK now.

Comment: So long as mod_wsgi.so links against Python shared library and not statically, a patch revision difference shouldn't matter. That said, maybe that mod_wsgi.so was compiled against a newer patch revision was the problem. Usually it would be other way around, where Python was updated but mod_wsgi wasn't. Glad to see you got it working at least.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try explicitly adding the django path to your sys.path?

```
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django')
```

(double check it's really there :) )

Comment: I added it in the django.wsgi file, and even printed it later to make sure its really there via the log....

Comment: @Harel wow you're getting a segmentation fault at `response = self.get_response(request)`! Can you copy into the question (pastebin or similar is great) the view that's supposed to answer to the url you are trying ? And also which middlewares you are using in the settings?

Comment: I updated the question. I'm quite surprised at this segfault, more so because it was sudden and stuck around after i rolled back any code changes. Thanks!